# Automatically move received ether from one address to another

Tags: ethereum, transfer, solidity, smartcontracts

Right now I am working on a smart contract with which, people are able to gamble.
 I want to introduce a small fee, a user has to pay every time they send ether to the smart contracts address. 
The fee should be automatically sent from the smart contract to my private ether wallet whenever someone starts a new game (sends ether to the contract) 

 since I am new to solidity and blockchain coding, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just transfer the amount you want (your fee) to your address.

i.e.

```
    uint256 yourFee = msg.value * percentFee;
    yourAdress.transfer(yourFee);
```

Don't forget to make the function `payable`.

Comment: Alternatively, to reduce the gas cost, you can just let them deposit funds into the contract, and withdraw into your private wallet from time to time.

Comment: but how do I set the trigger, that whenever someone sends eth to the address it starts you code?

Comment: just add this to whatever function your users are using to start a new game and to deposit money to your smart contract. it will then execute everytime a users does this. but you should consider carvers answer